# Can I use Lattice auto.key or key to make a legend with points for some data and lines for others?

Tags: legend, lattice

I often make figures that have observed data represented as points and model-predicted data represented as lines, using distribute.type to assign graph types. Is there a way to make a legend that only shows points for the points data, and lines for the lines data? The auto.key default is points, and if I add lines with "list(lines=TRUE)" the legend shows both points and lines for every data label:

```
x <- seq(0, 8*pi, by=pi/6)

Y1pred <- sin(x)
Y1obs <- Y1pred + rnorm(length(x), mean=0, sd=0.2)
Y2pred <- cos(x)
Y2obs <- Y2pred + rnorm(length(x), mean=0, sd=0.4)
 
xyplot(Y1obs + Y2obs + Y1pred + Y2pred ~ x, 
        type=c('p','p','l','l'), 
        distribute.type=TRUE,
        auto.key=list(lines=TRUE, columns=2)
        )
```

There is a rather complicated example using 'key' on p. 158 of Deepayans' book on Lattice, I am wondering if there are simple options?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, following S, the `lines` components of `key` supports different `type`-s (but not `points`). Using `auto.key`, you could do

```r
xyplot(Y1obs + Y2obs + Y1pred + Y2pred ~ x, 
       type=c('p','p','l','l'), 
       distribute.type=TRUE,
       auto.key = list(points = FALSE, lines = TRUE,
                       columns = 2,
                       type = c('p','p','l','l')))
```

Ideally, you would want to put the `type` only inside the `lines` component, and that's how you should do it if you use `key`. For `auto.key`, there can be only one line anyway, so this should be fine.